# Hadoop MapReduce to conditionally print name pairs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

So I am trying to figure out the logic for this MapReduce program question, I dont need the code, just need help with the logic since I am still new to MapReduce I am not very well acquainted with all the possible ways to tackle a problem. I tried looking up similar programs, but no luck.

Question:
Given a list of names (for simplicity just consider first characters)

Input:

```
A,B

D,F

P,E

A,B

A,C

B,A

E,P
```

I need to use MapReduce to print only those pairs(in alphabetical order) which are have been mentioned in alphabetical order and in the reverse order too.

So output will be:

```
A,B

E,P
```

Note: E,P is printed not P,E since it has to be in alphabetical order.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Map-Reduce programs the main question is: what will be a key, and what will be a value. Map-reduce programs work on key/value rules. You define key and value, on next step you can define other key and values, and so on. 
For example at the beginning the key is a index(number) of raw, and a value is the value in this raw. In code in `map` function you define new key, and value and went to `reduce` function where you go through all keys and make some action with values that have same key.

The classic example of map reduce is word count program.

In your example in your map function you can set a key `a pair in alphabetical order`, and the value will be  the  `pair itself` 
In reduce function you go through all values of every key and looks for reverse order, if you have reverse order, write this value to result

after map function output will be:

```
A,B A,B 
A,B A,B
A,B B,A
A,C A,C
D,F D,F
E,P P,E
E,P E,P
```

after reduce:

```
A,B A,B
P,E P,E
```

Comment: thank you so much! This makes sense, I am new to MapReduce and did not know what lines to think on. Using the name pair as the key was the key(pun unintended), I had not thought of it that way.
Thanks again! cheers :)